# TCP: Setting retransmits to zero

Tags: tcp, sysctl

I am using a linux machine.
I want to set the number of TCP retransmits to zero. I am using below command to modify:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries=0
```

The above command dont work and gives me below error:

```
error: "Invalid argument" setting key "net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries"
```

However, this command works -> `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries=1`
According to the documentation ->  `man tcp` :

> tcp_syn_retries (integer; default: 5; since Linux 2.2)
>                 The maximum number of times initial SYNs for an active TCP connection attempt will be retransmitted.  This value should not
>   be higher than 255.  The default value
>                 is 5, which corresponds to approximately 180 seconds.

Does setting `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries=0` means disabling syn or syn retries. I am unclear after reading the documentation.

Comment: 'I want to set the number of TCP retransmits to zero'. No you don't. Everything will break. Off topic.

Comment: tcp_syn_retries only change retries for initial SYN (i.e. SYN sent but not receiving SYN/ACK). You may simply assume that retransmission happens when a TCP packet was sent but no corresponding ACK  received, which I wonder there's really a TCP stack allows you to stop the retransmission. For a full picture you need to study the TCP protocol state diagram.